# The way of using images in Tkinter as icons for best performance

Tags: image, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, icons

Currently I am creating tkinter GUI app and I am using some images as icons for items in treeview widget. In order to read and keep them as a reference I used this code:

```
self.logoadd = tk.PhotoImage(file='../img/add.png')
self.logodel = tk.PhotoImage(file='../img/delete.png')
...
self.logoedit = tk.PhotoImage(file='../img/edit.png')

#Keep them as references
self.imgAdd = self.logoadd
self.imgDel = self.logodel
...
self.imgEdit = self.logoedit
```

And I think this is not a good practice if there are more than 30 images used. Another approaches which came to my head are:

- to store images as a byte string in .py file or;
- using for loop to retrieve all images in folder pass them as variable.

I need some advice from experienced GUI developers. Which way is the best in order to performance and used in GUI practices? (May be all of my ways are wrong)

**For info:** Size of these images is 16x16 and images used for file icons

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by _best performance_ because it seems like you are asking for a way to avoid writing out 30+ item assignments. If so then use a dictionary instead to hold all the `PhotoImage` and get it using the assigned key.

Comment: I mean by best performance is both speed and code. In treeview, there may be hundred items and their icons may differ. So reading proper images and putting them to GUI should be fast and easy to maintain.

Comment: Unless you have thousands or tens of thousands of images, the performance difference would be imperceptible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have used in multiple tkinter applications involving `PhotoImage` is to load the images into a dictionary to maintain a reference to them.

You can do it manually like so which is recommended if you have a few set images because it's easier to see what you have.

```
import tkinter as tk

image_cache = { 'add' : tk.PhotoImage(file = 'add.png'),
                ...
            }
```

Or the more compact and dynamic method is to use the `os` module and dictionary comprehension. Using this method all your keys will be the filename of your image to make accessing the images you want easier.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

filepath = '../img/'
image_cache = { os.path.splitext(filename)[0] : tk.PhotoImage(
    file = os.path.join(filepath, filename))
               for filename in os.listdir(filepath) }

>>> image_cache['add'] # gets the PhotoImage for 'add.png'
```

I am unsure if this method provides the best performance, however it is clean, compact and usable.

Comment: Big thanks, @Steven Summers. 2-variant suited  in my situation and worked well.